# How do I convert a markdown file with centered text in atom, using pandoc-convert to pdf?

Tags: html, pdf, markdown, atom-editor, pandoc

Since markdown does not have any options for centering text, but does allow html inline, I've added a  tag which works fine for converting to html, but not to pdf using the pandoc-convert package in atom.  How do I convert this file to pdf using pandoc-convert in atom while preserving the centered text.

```
---
geometry: margin=1.5cm  
---
<center>
<h1> My name</h1>
My Address   
myemail.com, my2ndemail.com    
+1 (999) 999-9999 (cell)    
</center>

#### Markdown Title
>Some block quoted text.
```

Comment: If your objective was just pdf, I would suggest this hackish answer: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2453#issuecomment-219233316 , where you define \Begin and \End latex commands. Then you can set \Begin{center} and \End{center} and they would work fine without having the text in between treated as latex. Since you want to be able to do *both*, one *verbose* option is to have \Begin and \End right before and after the div beginning and end. Alternatively, you could write a pandoc filter, which requires coding but solves the problem elegantly.

Answer (score 2):

The advice from the comment above worked.  In general, it appears the pandoc-convert in atom-editor works with latex commands for formatting the text.  Looks like I need to learn more LaTeX.  This is the code that worked for me in the end.

```
    ---
geometry: margin=1.5cm  
---

\begin{center}
\Huge My Name
\\ \small My Address
\\ myemail.com, my2ndemail.com    
\\ +1 (999) 999-9999 (cell)    
\end{center}

#### Markdown title
>Some block quoted text.
```