# How to align text using pandoc with lua-filters?

Tags: lua, markdown, pandoc

How to align all h1 headers of the pdf to center using pandoc with lua-filters?

I have the test.md file bellow:

```
<center>
# Chapter 1
</center>

<right>
## Sub-1-1
</right>

<left>
### Sub-1-2
</left>

<center>
# Chapter 2
</center>

<right>
## Sub-2-1
</right>

<left>
### Sub-2-2
</left>
```

And I need to align center all "Chapters" to center, all the "Sub-*-1" to right and all the "Sub-*-2" to left using tags as above, to stay like:

```html
            Chapter 1
                          Sub-1-1
Sub-1-2
            Chapter 2
                          Sub-2-1
Sub-2-2
```

I can uppcase the "Chapters"  with the follow filter.lua:

```lua
local text = require('text')

function Header(el)
    if el.level == 1 then
      return pandoc.walk_block(el, {
        Str = function(el)
            return pandoc.Str(text.upper(el.text))
        end })
    end
end
```

So I call the pandoc:

```sh
pandoc test.md -o test.pdf --pdf-engine=xelatex --lua-filter=./filter.lua
```

But I don't know how to align the things with lua-filters.

Comment: This is probably easier when done in LaTeX. Write the necessary LaTeX header snippets to a file and pass it to pandoc via `-H`. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8547

Comment: @tarleb I updated my question, I need with tags, because sometimes I need align, sometimes not, with LaTeX I already can do this, like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42239936/8211088, but I would like know how to make this with lua-filters yet.